# file.choose() does not pick up current directory first time after setwd()

Tags: r

I first changed my working directory in my `.Rprofile`. Next I tried to choose a file using `file.choose()`.

The first time I run `file.choose` it shows the default directory listing. Subsequent executions show form the current directory.

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/dinesh/Desktop/lab/M1/sp500"
> mydata=read.csv(file.choose(),stringsAsFactor=F,header=T)
Error in file.choose() : file choice cancelled <<<<<< wrong dir
> mydata=read.csv(file.choose(),stringsAsFactor=F,header=T)
Error in file.choose() : file choice cancelled <<<<<<<<<<<< right dir
```

OTOH if in second command I were to run `list.files()` I would get the correct listing. And again, first invocation of `file.choose` will behave unexpectedly.

NEXT I changed the current dir again, to `setwd("c:/Users")` and tried `list.files()` and `file.choose()` and got the same pattern of outcomes.

Why does it behave this way, or, what am I missing? I am using R 3.1.2 on Windows 7.

--EDIT added more details

From Profile:

```
if (readline("Wanna pick a new working dir (by choosing a file)? y/xyz: ") == "y") {
  try(setwd(dirname(file.choose())))
}
```

Using RGui

From `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: R-Studio, or R-Gui? And which version? Maybe post your `.Rprofile` and `sessionInfo()` here as well.

Comment: I don't think there is supposed to be any "guarantee" that `file.choose` will produce a dialog box initially focused on the current working directory (as in `list.files`). This is not explicitly noted in its help file, so the default behavior of this function may be platform dependent.

Comment: @nrussell So I tried `choose.files()` whose man page says it will start in the current dir and again got the same behavior.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure; sounds like a "Windows" thing. FWIW you will encounter a lot less of these "surprises" on Linux.

Comment: @nrussell thanks! I upgraded to R3.2.3 (win64) and the problem is gone :)

Comment: I think I spoke too soon :(

Comment: I see this as well (R 3.2.2 x86_64-w64-mingw32; RStudio  0.99.837). If my initial wd is 'foo', the first call to `file.choose()` (or `choose.files()` after `setwd('bar')` still shows path 'foo'. Subsequent calls correctly show path 'bar'.